# how could I check that whether a S3 bucket already exist in aws s3 with GO

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I am trying to find an efficient way to check whether a bucket exist in aws S3 service.
I don't want to use the list bucket function of s3 go sdk 'listBuckets'
I tried using 'headBucket' function but I think i am using it in the wrong way. any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

headBucket is the right method if it is your bucket. 
This way you can check if the bucket exists.

If you mean globally I would try to create the bucket with a uuid at the end.
If the bucket already exists you will get the error:

```
ErrCodeBucketAlreadyExists "BucketAlreadyExists".
```

Does this help?

Greetings

Dominik

Comment: actually the case is, I am working with aws-go-sdk and trying to know before hand that if any bucket exist with this name, there are many buckets with different owners so 'headBucket' is not helpful

Comment: Then you have the global use case. You cannot know beforehand if the3 bucket exists, but will get the BucketAlreadyExists error and can handle this accordingly